# Lookup table and get column from another table using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, lookup, using

I have below two spark dataframes as below.

df1---->

```
ID  col1 col2
---------------
001 abd   xyz
002 eny   opl
001 uyh   ikl
003 ewr   uji
002 opl   rtn
001 jnu   wbg
```

df2------>

```
ID col3 col4
-------------
001 acc1 jbo
002 acc1 unk
003 acc2 plo
004 acc3 edf
005 acc2 tgn
006 acc1 jhu
```

expected output--->

```
ID  col1 col2 col3
---------------
001 abd   xyz acc1
002 eny   opl acc1
001 uyh   ikl acc1
003 ewr   uji acc3
002 opl   rtn acc1
001 jnu   wbg acc1
```

Can someone suggest the solution to obtain the expected output using pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Left join on `ID`:

```
df1.join(df2, ['ID'], 'left').drop('col4').show()
+---+----+----+----+
| ID|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|001| abd| xyz|acc1|
|002| eny| opl|acc1|
|001| uyh| ikl|acc1|
|003| ewr| uji|acc2|
|002| opl| rtn|acc1|
|001| jnu| wbg|acc1|
+---+----+----+----+
```